# How do I align columns in thead and tbody when tbody css display attribute is block

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table with thead, tbody and tfoot.
The css value for display is block - enables adding a scrollbar to the body and scroll the rows while the thead and tfoot stay in place.
The TD tags widths are not fixed as the tables width changes according to the width of the TD.
I would like to align the thead's TH tags with the tbody's TD tags.

How can this be done?
(CSS or JQuery)

**Edit:**
The target browser is Google - Chrome! 
 
And adding a slight twist, the Table is RTL.

**The CSS:**

```
tbody{
    display: block;
    overflow: auto;
}

thead, tfoot{
    display: block;
}
```

**The HTML:**

```
    <table>
        <caption>My Table</caption>
        <thead>    
            <tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>    
            <tr><td>Cell11</td><td>Cell12</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell21</td><td>Cell22</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell31</td><td>Cell32</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell41</td><td>Cell42</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell51</td><td>Cell52</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Cell61 Is Wide</td><td>Cell62</td></tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr><th>6 Rows</th><th></th></tr>
        </tfoot>                
    </table>
```

You can try it using this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Julian/VHk7K/)**.

Thanks and be happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use JS or jQuery to access the `offsetWidth` of the cells in the first row of the `tbody` and then set those as explicit `width` styles for the `th`. You can iterate the row in the tbody and head in unison by using the index from one iteration to access the element in the other.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. How do I take the scrollbar into consideration?

Comment: @Julian Good question; what do you hope would happen? Should it be included in the width of the last column, or show up to the right of last header?

Comment: I didn't mention in the question that the table is RTL so actually it is the first column. I guess that in case there is a scrollbar I need to indent the header by the value of the width of the scrollbar. Do you know of a simple way to do that?

Comment: @Julian CSS? `thead th:last-child { padding-right:16px } /* or whatever size */`

Comment: Does this solution require style="table-layout: fixed;"

Comment: @Grae No, explicitly setting the widths on one item in the column for every column will fix the layout already.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow` for `tbody` is not supported by all browsers!!

Update: you might have to create min. two tables for the headers and one for the content and put the second on inside `div` and use `overflow` and you have to sync the columns width using javascipt.

Comment: You are right I am developing for Google Chrome - forgot to mention that - I will add it to my question. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @Julian actually not, I prefer to use a ready made grids for my system like jqGrid. this link might help u http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/30/tables-and-data-grids-with-ajax-dhtml-javascript/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have voted up for that - Do you by any chance know if the grids are compatible with RTL languages ;-)

Comment: @Julian I did some digging and found there someone make ExtJS grid supports RTL. Grid: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-2 RTL Support: https://github.com/mksoft/ExtJS-RTL