# Making table's <tbody> scrollable using display:block and offsetWidth

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to make a table tbody scrollable, and reading [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126670/how-do-i-align-columns-in-thead-and-tbody-when-tbody-css-display-attribute-is-bl) SO question I found out
that I have to apply a `display: block;` plus `overflow` and a fixed `height` to the table's `tbody`.

Also, to set the `tbody` width to match the `thead` width, I need to set the `offsetWidth` for the first row's `td`.

This is what I've tried so far: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/qPMP3/)

As you can see, the table `tbody` is not taking the right amount of space.. Changing the `offsetWidth` seems not to be the right thing (or I'm doin'g it wrong):

```
$("tbody tr:first-child").find("td").each(function (index) {
    this.offsetWidth = this.style.width;
});
```

I need every tbody td, to be aligned with his th column "bestfriend".

Any idea? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
    <div id="wrap1">
    <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Header one</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Header two</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Header three</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Header four</th>
                <th style="width: 20%;">Header five</th>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="wrap2">
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;">content</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">content</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">content</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">content</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;">content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
                <td>content</td>
            </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="output"></div>

#wrap1 {
width: 400px;
height:50px;
```

}

```
#wrap2 {
    width: 417px;
    height:150px;
    overflow-y:auto;
}
#wrap1 tr {
    background:lightblue;
    position:alsolute;
}

#wrap2 tr {
    background: lightgray;
}




$(document).ready(function () {
    $("tbody tr:first-child").find("td").each(function (index) {
        this.offsetWidth = this.style.width;
        $("#output").append("[ #" + (index+1) + " td ] width: " + this.style.width + " | offsetWidth: " + this.offsetWidth + "<br>");

    });
});
```

Comment: the title says: "TBODY SCROLLABLE", not the entire table

Comment: what is wrong with you? TBODY SCROLLABLE !!! NOT THE WHOLE TABLE, read the damn description

Comment: TBODY == <tbody> != <thead>

Comment: that completely changed my table structure, I know I can achieve that splitting it into 2 portions, but I need to find a way to get the same result without splitting the table. Thanks anyway for the hint

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/). I was skeptical at first but now I use them for everything. They support a lot of functionality, from [exporting](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/button_options) files, to [filtering](http://www.datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering), tbody [scrolling](http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_y.html) etc. You are going to love them...

EDIT: And not to mention they are free, and they work in most major browsers...

Comment: if I could, I would.. but I can't. Thanks anyway for the suggestion :)

Comment: dude, i've been trying to make it work in your fiddle, i'm close but not quite yet there, i'll let you know. your selector it definitely wrong though, as because of the `each()` statement, `this` always refers to the the current cell. but i think that you should refer to the `th` for the specific index. let me give it one more try :)